# how to overwrite destination file(s) using MSBuild command line in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, command-line, msbuild

I am using MSBuild in Jenkins to generate a SharePoint package using the following command line:

```
/p:Configuration=Release /p:OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=true /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath="c:\temp\"
```

Now, I would like to overwrite the destination file or files if they exist.
How can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
You can simply run clean command first
Msbuild "c:\dev\my.sln" /t:clean /p:configuration=

And now run your regular build command.

Option 2:
Delete all output folder
rm /f /s "c:\dev\release"

Now run your regular build

Let me know solved it for you...